# How do I make elements that are generated after page load (ajax) become draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

I have a div on my page that gets populated via an ajax call to separate php script every 2000ms.  When the user checks a checkbox, the update interval stops and all the items in the div need to become draggable.  If I do this without the update interval it works, but once I have the div reloading the items loose their draggability.  How can I maintain the their draggable property?

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    $(window).load(function() {
      getScreen ();
    });


    var editMode = false;
    var intervalId = window.setInterval(getScreen ,2000);

    function getScreen () {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
          {
            document.getElementById("refresh").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
          }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","getScreen.php?sid="+<?php echo $sid; ?>,true);
        xmlhttp.send(); 

    }

    function onEditMode(cb) {
      if(cb.checked) { 
        editMode = true; 
        $('.item').draggable( 'enable' );
        window.clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
      else { 
        editMode = false;
        $('.item').draggable( 'disable' );
        intervalId = window.setInterval(getScreen ,2000); 
      }  
    }

    </SCRIPT>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div id="content">      
      <div class="post">            
         <div id="refresh">
         </div>     
      </div>        
    </div>
```

Comment: I thought the benefits from using a framework are simplicity.. why are you writing your own XHR requests? http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. And for your question: look at the docs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make items draggable/non-draggable in the Ajax callback after you overwrite the container HTML. Since once is HTML overwritten, any attached DOM listeners are lost.

```
var refresh = $('#refresh');
refresh.html(xmlhttp.responseText);
$('.item', refresh).draggable('enable');
```

And yes, as @pduersteler said, jQuery has excellent Ajax facilities. <s>[`load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) method  does exactly what you do — loads HTML into a container.</s> [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is a way to go.

Also, you'd better replace `setInterval` with a `setTimeout` *inside the Ajax callback*. It will ensure smoother update experience.

```
var postData = { sid: <?=sid?> };

var container = $('#refresh');

var ajaxCallback = function (data) {
    container.html(data);

    var items = $('.item', container);

    if (editMode) {
        items.draggable('enable');
    } else {
        items.draggable('disable');
        setTimeout(getScreen, 2000);
    }
};

function getScreen() {
    $.post('/getScreen.php', postData, ajaxCallback);
}

getScreen();
```

Comment: Thanks for the great answer, but it seems like the ajaxCallback function is still getting called before the .load() method populates the div so the items are not available to become draggable yet.  I put a debug break in the callback function and it gets hit before the div is loaded.

Comment: Then you'll have to use `$.post()`, I guess. See updated answer.

Comment: I am getting the same behavior with .post().  Even if I pause right after $('#refresh').html(data); the div is not loaded yet.

Comment: Ok, I got the items loaded before trying to make them draggable by using your code and moving "var container = $('#refresh');" to the first line of the callback function.  But for some reason the items do not actually become draggable...

Comment: Figured it out!  Your code works.  I just had other errors in the page.  Thanks.